# RHEL Developer subscription not finding repos

Tags: rhel

I've been signed up for the Redhat Developer program for a while.  I needed to do some tests in the RHEL 7.5 VM that had been working with the subscription program.  When I reverted and did an update, I was able to get updates.  However, I need to access some items via the downloads and had to change password on the site.

I unregistered my subscription and re-registered using new password. Now when I use subscription manager to list repos. It says returns:

```
$ sudo subscription-manager repos --list
This system has no repositories available through subscriptions.
```

It seems as though I have nothing but problems with subscription-manager.  Is there something that I'm doing wrong with the Developer program?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally found the [answer in the RedHat knowledge base](https://access.redhat.com/discussions/3066851).  I still don't understand why it's so difficult to use.

You may want to clean up first:

```
sudo subscription-manager remove --all
sudo subscription-manager unregister
sudo subscription-manager clean
```

Re-register and attach:

```
sudo subscription-manager register
sudo subscription-manager refresh
sudo subscription-manager attach --auto
```

List repost and attach:

```
Execute sudo subscription-manager repos --list-enabled to see all actually enabled subscriptions.
Execute sudo subscription-manager repos --list to see all subscriptions that are available for you.
Execute sudo subscription-manager repos --enable <repo> if you want to add additional repos.
```